# Clickhouse create database structure for json data

Tags: clickhouse

New to clickhouse and stuck on the database creation structure for importing json data which is nested

Take for example the json data that looks like the following

when there is data populated

```
"FirewallMatchesActions": [
    "allow"
  ],
  "FirewallMatchesRuleIDs": [
    "1234abc"
  ],
  "FirewallMatchesSources": [
    "firewallRules"
  ],
```

or

```
"FirewallMatchesActions": [
    "allow",
    "block"
  ],
  "FirewallMatchesRuleIDs": [
    "1234abc",
    "1235abb"
  ],
  "FirewallMatchesSources": [
    "firewallRules"
  ],
```

but there maybe json data which doesn't have them populated

```
  "FirewallMatchesActions": [],
  "FirewallMatchesRuleIDs": [],
  "FirewallMatchesSources": [],
```

what would the clickhouse create database structure look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickHouse supports types of columns as [Array](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/array/) as [Nested](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/nested-data-structures/nested/).

It looks like for your case Array will be enough:

```sql
CREATE TABLE json_import (
  TimeStamp DateTime DEFAULT now(),

  /* other columns */

  FirewallMatchesActions Array(String),
  FirewallMatchesRuleIDs Array(String),
  FirewallMatchesSources Array(String)
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY (TimeStamp);

/* insert test data */

INSERT INTO json_import (FirewallMatchesActions, FirewallMatchesRuleIDs, FirewallMatchesSources)
VALUES (['allow'], ['1234abc', '1235abb'], ['firewallRules']), 
       (['allow', 'block'], ['1234abc'], ['firewallRules']), 
       ([], [], []);

/* select data */
SELECT *
FROM json_import

/* result
┌───────────TimeStamp─┬─FirewallMatchesActions─┬─FirewallMatchesRuleIDs─┬─FirewallMatchesSources─┐
│ 2020-06-12 06:06:17 │ ['allow']              │ ['1234abc','1235abb']  │ ['firewallRules']      │
│ 2020-06-12 06:06:17 │ ['allow','block']      │ ['1234abc']            │ ['firewallRules']      │
│ 2020-06-12 06:06:17 │ []                     │ []                     │ []                     │
└─────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
*/
```

---

To reduce storage consumption consider using [LowCardinality](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/lowcardinality/)-type and [data encoding](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/#create-query-specialized-codecs).

---

Additional info:

[Nested Data Structures in ClickHouse](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2017/8/30/nested-data-structures-in-clickhouse)

[Reducing Clickhouse Storage Cost with the LowCardinality Type – Lessons from an Instana Engineer](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2020/5/20/reducing-clickhouse-storage-cost-with-the-low-cardinality-type-lessons-from-an-instana-engineer)

[New Encodings to Improve ClickHouse Efficiency](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2019/7/new-encodings-to-improve-clickhouse)

Comment: thanks vladimir for the explanation and tips ! With LowCardinality how would that be set for Array(String) ? like


`Array(LowCardinality(String))`

Comment: no problem. You are right need to use *Array(LowCardinality(String))*.